# how to integrate sharepoint website with android client application?

Tags: android, web, integration, synchronization

Dear all i need a help please

I have a sharepoint website and the task is to make an android client application to integrate with this website ,
this application will just view the content of the website and add comment feedback.

i don't know what is the steps to do this task ,i just want steps to follow to start this app

thank you all waiting your answers

Answer (score 0):

Opening a simple browser. Sharepoint has a layout for mobile display (it is still not light, but at least should render correctly).

Or call the Sharepoint web-services with SOAP if you want a deeper integration.

In both cases, you shouls handle the authentitification if the Microsoft IIS server is set up to require one.

Comment: what about using REST ,or if i want to make database sync between the website and mobile app???

Comment: REST is definitely easier, indeed. Apparently Sharepoint 2010 supports RESTful services. Sharepoint 2007 doesn't natively.

Comment: so if the website was sharepoint 2010 u recommend REST.and if u can provide me with sample code and steps to how to make this integration to follow coz i'm beginner in android ..Thanks again for help

Comment: There is a search engine on stackoverflow.